# Cómo ocultar un email con asteriscos o pipe?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pipe

Tengo este pipe

```
export class HideReferralPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, ): string {
     return value
      ? value.replace(/\B.+@/g, (c, ) => c.split('').slice(0, -1).map(v => '*').join('') + '@') 
      : value;
  }
```

La salida al aplicarlos sobre un text:

```
f*******@gmail.com
```

Como tendría que ser la expresion regular para obtener el siguiente resultado?:

```
fer*****@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo usar esta otra RegEx:

```
/[a-z0-9\-_.]+@/ig
```

En detalle seria:

- `[a-z0-9\-_.]`: Grupo de caracteres de la `a-z`, del `0-9`, `-`, `_` o `.`.
- `+`: Uno o mas de los caracteres en el grupo.
- `@`: caracter `@`

Esta RegExp te permite ocultar correctamente mails como:

- `f.ernando@`
- `f_ernando@`
- `f-ernando@`

Utilizando esta RegExp, en la función *"reemplazadora"* tenemos que:

- Obtener los 3 primeros caracteres (`eg: c.substr(0, 3)`)
- Sacar los 3 primeros caracteres y el último (`eg: c.split('').slice(3, -1)`) para luego ocultar los restantes.

#### Demo:

```js
let value = 'f.ernando@gmail.com';
let chars = 3; // Cantidad de caracters visibles

let res = value.replace(/[a-z0-9\-_.]+@/ig, (c) => c.substr(0, chars) + c.split('').slice(chars, -1).map(v => '*').join('') + '@')
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Era lo que buscaba